# Checking sudoku puzzle validity in c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm writing a program that takes a set of number triplets and creates a sudoku puzzle using the first two numbers in each triplet to index a 2d array and the last as the actual number to go into the puzzle. Part of the program is the validation to make sure each number in the puzzle is not repeated in the same row, column, or 3x3 block. I have already written the code to check the row and column, but I'm not sure how to go about the 3x3 block part. I can think of a couple of ways that would work (e.g setting a third array dimension and flagging each number based on location in the array) but everything I can think of would be a long, painful process. Is there a simpler way to do this that I haven't thought of?

Comment: possible duplicate of [duplicacy problems while creating a sudoku puzzle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571009/duplicacy-problems-while-creating-a-sudoku-puzzle)

Answer (score 0):

A simple way of going about it, in pseudocode:

- For each 3x3 block (x<sub>block</sub>, y<sub>block</sub> ∈ {0, 3, 6}):

  - For each cell within the block (x<sub>1</sub>, y<sub>1</sub> ∈ {0, 1, 2}):

    - For each other cell within the block (x<sub>2</sub>, y<sub>2</sub> ∈ {0, 1, 2}):

      - If the value at (x<sub>1</sub>, y<sub>1</sub>) equals the value at (x<sub>2</sub>, y<sub>2</sub>), and x<sub>1</sub> ≠ x<sub>2</sub> or y<sub>1</sub> ≠ y<sub>2</sub>:

        - The block is invalid.

A block is valid unless proved invalid.

Comment: An implementation detail : you can just check and set bits in an unsigned int, rather than having a double loop over all cells  in the block.

Comment: @MichaelAnderson: Right. This is by no means an efficient solution, but the input size is so small that it doesn’t really matter. The OP seems to be a relative beginner and this was the plainest, most straightforward thing I could think of.